# “in turn” or “in return” - which is correct in this sentence?

Tags: word-usage

> Your gift is the most immediate way that you can help our school which **{in return / in turn}** provides tuition assistance to families in need, bolsters academic programs, and enhances our students' experience.

“in turn” or “in return” - which is correct in this sentence?

Comment: Can you add to your question why you are puzzled by these two words.  Why do you think "return" might be replaced by "turn".   Why are you asking about these words and not any of the others?

Comment: Related question: [What does “in turn” mean here?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/7184/9161)

Answer (score 1):

*in return* implies an exchange: *You give me a ride to the event, and in return I'll cook a dinner for you.*

*in turn* implies a sequence: *Each player chooses a card in turn* = *The players take turns choosing a card.*

*in turn* is correct here because the sentence describes a sequence (you give money, and then the school gives money) without exchange (the school does nothing to help the donor).

This is not to say that *return* is never appropriate in similar contexts.  *You pledge a dollar a month, and in return you get quality entertainment* : here each party provides value to the other.  Neither action must precede the other, so *in turn* would not fit.

Answer (score 0):

Both "in return" and "in turn" imply that the latter event (tuition assistance, etc.) happens as a result of the first event (your gift).

However, if you want to compare the two, take a look at this page: https://hinative.com/en-US/questions/207386

In short, "in return" works best in your sentence!